# I want to generate a random number and the use it in another class to generate random names

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is the code where I am stuck with the converting the int to string ans also at the same time wanted to know how can I use it in another class

```
public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    String randnumber = r.toString();
}
```

so here its a type mismatch and also I want to use this random number in my next script

```
String id = pagehelper.RandomNumber(String min, String max);
firstName.sendKeys("FirstName"+id);
lastName.sendKeys("LastName"+id);
```

Comment: can you defined the relation between generating the random number with random names ? Are you getting the random names from an array after getting random number ?

Comment: Also nothing can execute after the `return`, so you will also have to fix that.  (If you just want to convert the integer itself to a string, you can do that with string concatenation: `"FirstNam" + id` will convert `id` to a string if it is an integer.)

Answer (score 2):

Have the method return a string instead of an int. I also  made the method static since it doesn’t reference any class members and changed name to start with lowercase since that is the praxis for naming java methods

```
public static String randomNumber(int min, int max) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int temp = r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return r.toString();
}
```